# MATCH and LOOKUP returning unexpected values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function

**UPDATE WITH ANSWER**:

I misunderstood the operation of `MATCH` and `LOOKUP`; they apparently do not automatically select the last value.

The updated formula is as follows:

```
=IF(
    ISNUMBER( MATCH(2,INDEX(1/($D2=$D$1:$D1),0)) ), 
    ($A2+$B2) - (LOOKUP(2,1/($D2=$D$1:$D1),$A$1:$A1)+LOOKUP(2,1/($D2=$D$1:$D1),$B$1:$B1))
    ,0 )
```

The main differences are that `MATCH` is now `MATCH(2,INDEX(1/($D2=$D$1:$D1),0))` and `LOOKUP` is now `LOOKUP(2,1/($D2=$D$1:$D1),$A$1:$A1)`.

Thanks barry houdini and Nanashi for their help!

---

I am working on what was supposed to be a simple spreadsheet, but one of my formulas is giving me unanticipated results. A screenshot of my data can be seen below:

![Spreadsheet Screenshot][1]

In column C, I am trying to get the time difference between the previous data point with the same type and the current data point. My formula (formatted for easier reading, and taken at cell C11) is as follows:

```
=IF(
    NOT( ISNA( MATCH($D11,$D$1:$D10,1) ) ),
    ($A11+$B11)-(
        LOOKUP($D11,$D$1:$D10,$A$1:$A10)+LOOKUP($D11,$D$1:$D10,$B$1:$B10)
    ),FALSE)
```

The cell numbering changes for the appropriate cell–for example, C10 references $D10 and the range $D$1:$D9, etc.

- The conditional (`NOT( ISNA( MATCH($D11,$D$1:$D10,1) ) )` checks to make sure that in column C there is a previous value that equals the current one; otherwise it returns `FALSE`, as it does in rows 1 and 12.
- The calculation `($A11+$B11)-(LOOKUP($D11,$D$1:$D10,$A$1:$A10)+LOOKUP($D11,$D$1:$D10,$B$1:$B10)` takes the current row date and time and subtracts the date and time in the row corresponding with the previous instance of the same type (the `LOOKUP` function is supposed to return the last occurrence of a value in an array, according to the documentation).

**My issue is this: after row 12, the `MATCH` and `LOOKUP` functions are all picking up row 11 as the last row in which column C has the value of 1.** I've tried testing them separately, and both functions return their appropriate values from row 11. For example, putting the following formula in E16: `=MATCH(1,$D$1:$D16,1)` returned 11 when I would expect the value to be 16.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: D11 refers to the value, which in this spreadsheet is 1–I'm searching the range D1:D10 for the last value equal to 1. I don't believe that is the issue since I use similar techniques regularly, and the discrepancy is still present if I explicitly put 1 instead of D11.

Comment: Yes, noticed that much, which is why my comment was not applicable. Hm. It looks formulaically correct. Will attempt to recreate your data set on my end. Is `Type` hardcoded or is there a method to it?

Comment: What is your expected output now? For example, in C17, what should be showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `MATCH` nor `LOOKUP` will find the "last occurrence" as you require with unsorted data. Try these versions for last row/match:

`=MATCH(2,INDEX(1/($D11=$D$1:$D10),0))`

`=LOOKUP(2,1/($D11=$D$1:$D10),$B$1:$B10)`

....for your specific requirement you can get both date and time in one `LOOKUP`, e.g.

`=$A11+$B11-LOOKUP(2,1/($D11=$D$1:$D10),$A$1:$A10+$B$1:$B10)`

which explicitly uses the dates in column A - if you have data for every day, so you can always assume that change of day is to the **next** day then you can leave out the date references and use `MOD` like this:

`=MOD($B11-LOOKUP(2,1/($D11=$D$1:$D10),$B$1:$B10),1)`

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that `MATCH` is not programmed to return the index of the *latest* matching value. That said, a formula that gets this for us will solve the problem.

Enter the following formula in `C2` and drag down:

```
=MOD((B2)-INDEX(B:B,SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($D$1:$D1=D2)*ROW($D$1:$D1)))),1)
```

Broken down, this is what each part does:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(MAX(($D$1:$D1=D2)*ROW($D$1:$D1))) 'Returns the row of the latest match.
=INDEX(B:B, SUMPRODUCT...) 'Returns the matching cell in Column B.
=MOD(B2 - INDEX(...),1) 'Gets the absolute difference, no need to add A and B.
```

Result:

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

EDIT: Changed formula as per Barry's correction.

Comment: That helps a lot - thanks! The only issue that I see is that PM to AM delta calculations aren't correct (I've updated the image above with some more data I collected this morning) - I imagine that conditionally subtracting the calculation from 1 will work; but I'll play with it.

Comment: Kindly mark the answer as accepted if you found it helpful. I think the absolute value will compute it correctly, regardless, but adjust the formula if otherwise. :)

Comment: @Lee - see my answer that will work when going to the next day

Comment: Ah, I see. In my pre-edit answer, I also did an `A1+B1` sort of answer, but decided to stick to `ABS` instead. Oh well.

Comment: @Nanashi - nice answer!....but ABS doesn't work because e.g. `=ABS("3:00"-"22:00")` gives `19:00` when answer needs to be `5:00` - you can get that with `=MOD("3:00"-"22:00",1)`

Comment: Aha! Yes, `MOD` it is, and not `ABS`. Anyway, leaving this up there just for FYI.